# Design 1-Wire slave device to get the state of a switch

Tags: 1-wire

I have an MCB (Miniature Circuit Breaker) whose state has to be communicated over 1-Wire. I can get the MCB state as 0/5V signal. How can I develop this to act as a 1-Wire Slave device so that it can communicate with a 1-Wire Master device?

Please give me some hints/guidelines as to how to achieve my goal.

**EDIT 1**

I have previously done communication over 1-wire by interfacing a 1-wire temperature sensor with an Arduino. But my requirement is to design a *1-wire switch state monitor* device which can act as a 1-Wire slave.

**EDIT 2**

I am looking for something like a small uP so that I can connect HIGH/LOW input to it and the uP then transmits it to the 1-Wire bus. I am looking for this kind of solution. Only READ operation has to be supported. I cannot use an Arduino as a slave due to cost constraints. There will be 5-8 MCBs whose statuses have to be recorded.

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting? What have you considered so far? Have you done microcontroller programming before? What electronics background do you have? Where *exactly* are you stuck? Please edit your question to add that information, don't answer in comments. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I updated my question with what you requested. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Unfortunately that edit doesn't contain the detail I was hoping for. I'm still not sure where *exactly* you are stuck. For example, if you've done Arduino programming before, then have you looked for libraries which allow an Arduino to emulate 1-wire slave devices? If you are stuck with Arduino programming, then [Arduino StackExchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask. If (as it seems) you want hints and suggestions, then that isn't a specifically answerable question (insufficient constraints / too broad). Sorry I can't add more :-(

Comment: I've seen 1-wire 8-input chips on some devices. Have a look.

Comment: You could re-use your previous project, and when the switch is closed it powers a resistor which heats up, which is then sensed by the temperature sensor and then sent via 1 wire to the Arduino. Mr. Goldberg would be proud!

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for your input. I added **EDIT 2** and I would be glad if you can take a look at that 'edit'.

Comment: I think you can use DS2413 to convert high/low signal to one-wire "package".

Answer (score 1):

For a device that can receive/transmit UART can be used with external components to talk to 1 wire slave.

1. https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/2/214.html
2. https://www.eeweb.com/profile/ixys/articles/uart-to-implement-a-1-wire-master

But your slave device is just a breaker, you can't send anything to it. What else would it transmit besides HIGH and LOW? Why is your current setup unacceptable? i.e. breaker output tied to an Arduino digital input pin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I will take a look at the links you've shared. Anyway, I cannot use an Arduino as a slave due to cost constraints. I need something like an 8-bit uP so that I can connect HIGH/LOW input to it and the uP then transmits it to the 1-Wire bus. I am looking for this kind of solution.

Comment: @LakmalPremaratne Did you solve your problem?

Comment: My overall setup was changed and I no longer have to bother with 1-Wire. So I didn't pursue a solution any further. Thank you for your follow up. (Y)